# spring:message, how to get all messages with key 'beginning with'

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

So I have a bunch of messages in my messages file with keys like

```
alt.text1=Hello
alt.text2=Goodbye
```

In my JSP I can fetch and display these just fine with

```
<spring:message code="alt.text1"/>
<spring:message code="alt.text2"/>
```

Which renders as

```
Hello Goodbye
```

Question is, how I can fetch all the messages whose key's start with 'alt'. IE I want to display all the 'alt' messages a once but not any of the other messages in the file that don't start with alt.

I understand the messages are a hashmap in the JSP, how can I access this map to iternate over its keys and values for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating a `CustomerMessageSource` as below and placing the result of listAllAltLabels onto the view. Then it was a simple case of iterating over that.

```
public class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

    public Map<String, String> listAllAltLabels(String basename, Locale locale) {
        Map<String, String> altLabels = new HashMap<String, String>();

        PropertiesHolder propertiesHolder = getMergedProperties(locale);
        Properties properties = propertiesHolder.getProperties();

        for(Object key : properties.keySet()){
            if(((String)key).startsWith("alt.")) {
                altLabels.put((String)key, (String)properties.get(key));
            }
        }

        return altLabels;
    } 

}
```

I use spring webflow (hides most controllers) but basically somewhere in the controller/action before rendering the page, call the listAllAltLabels and assign the result to "altLabelMessages" and place it into the Model/View.

Then in the view (jsp)

```
<c:forEach items="${altLabelMessages}" var="message">
    <form:option value="${message.key}" label="${message.value}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hi sorry... I don't see where you are loading properties files.  Did you do this on a different method? Thank you for sharing this....

Comment: What is `PropertiesHolder`? I can't find this class in the Spring Context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Spring, but it looks like there is no [tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html) to get a message bundle using Spring.

If you would use `<fmt:setBundle/>` you will get a [`LocalizationContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/fmt/LocalizationContext.html) object, which contains a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). Unfortunately the [`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#keySet%28%29) method is not accessible using expression language.

What you could do is load the message bundle in a bean and create a list of keys starting with `alt.`, or just expose the entire key set.